# jquery clear click event and modify this event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In Issue form, I have one IFrame which has "Show Comments" and "Email Service Guide" click function. The function is when click "Email Service Guide", open Email form.

What I want to modify is...
When i click "Email Service Guide", I want to show confirm meassage box firstly. If choose "ok", want to show Email form. Else choose "Cancel", don't show any form.

I use the jquery selector, but the problem is the code showing directly the Email form firstly. What should i do? I also attach the form style and Html IFRAME portion. Thanks..
please give me some suggestion.[image]![image]

```
$('#kbviewer').load(function () {
    $(this).contents().find('#btnEmailArticle').click(function () {
        var msg = confirm('The guide selected is for internal circulation. Click OK to proceed or Click Cancel.');
            if (msg) {
            window.execScript(action);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ah, suffer the ingrates... they know not what they do ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should use `style="display:none"` on the iframe, and then `show()` the iframe ...

```
$('#kbviewer').load(function () {
    $(this).contents().find('#btnEmailArticle').click(function () {
        var msg = confirm('The guide selected is for internal circulation. Click OK to proceed or Click Cancel.');
            if (msg) {
            $('#iframe').show();
            window.execScript(action);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#kbviewer').load(function () {
    $(this).contents().find('#btnEmailArticle').click(function(event) {
        var msg = confirm('The guide selected is for internal circulation. Click OK to proceed or Click Cancel.');
            if (msg) {
            window.execScript(action);
            } else {
             event.preventDefault(); 
            }
        });
    });
```